# Is it professional to ask about compensation when offered relocation and training to a foreign country?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, relocation

If one is verbally offered relocation for a job in a foreign country, is it appropriate to ask about the terms of compensation (i.e. salary, medical benefits, etc.?) before moving forward, e.g. the company is getting ready to find housing, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> If one is verbally offered relocation for a job in a foreign country,
>   is it appropriate to ask about the terms of compensation

**Yes, it's appropriate.**

Any time you are offered what is essentially a new job, I think you are entitled to learn about all the components of that job, before accepting that offer.

To me, compensation changes, currency, relocation assistance, training, etc - these are all completely relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. It is normal to discuss all aspects of compensation before moving forward, to verify that they are acceptable to you. This is especially important when a potential international relocation is involved, as the costs for going back if the compensation isn't sufficient would be far higher that with, say, a position in your current location.

Answer (score 0):

I think, absolutely! Just focus before on your awesome technical skills, and then introduce the subject, politely but firmly. saying that, as it looks like we are seriously talking about that,and the relocation to another country is obviously a complicated process involving all kinds of everything, you'd need to know the details of your contract to make an informed decision. I'd just present myself as a happy worker, happy in your country, but also happy to move if the conditions are right. They should get the impression you are an excellent hire, but not an experiment or an adventurer.